# Variable in config.inc.php

Tags: php, variables, config

I have a filemanager that uses a config.inc.php file. I'm wondering how to use a predefined variable in this file, but i have no idea how.

I would like to know how this syntax is called and how i can use a variable.

```
;<?php/* do not delete this line!
[FTP]

; FTP access; leave empty to use local file system instead
ftpHost = "127.0.0.1"   ; FTP server name
ftpUser = "test"        ; FTP user name
ftpPassword = "test"    ; FTP password
ftpPort = 21            ; FTP port number (default is 21)
ftpPassiveMode = yes    ; use passive mode
ftpSSL = no             ; use FTPS 
                        ; do not delete this line! */?>
```

Comment: Put them in array? I probably don't understand the question...

Comment: are you looking for `parse_ini_file`?

Comment: Syntax looks like that of the PHP.ini file. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Comment: This is the file i have, and i want to edit it. I want to use something like: ftpUser = $varUser. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to parse ini file to extract values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764254/need-to-parse-ini-file-to-extract-values)

Comment: No, you can't assign a varibale to presaved constant like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an `INI` file that is protected by PHP tags and readed with `parse_ini_file`

add after:

```
ftpSSL = no             ; use FTPS
```

this:

```
customVar = "var"       ; custom variable
```

You can add other variables but I don't think you can assign one from outside.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, this is what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the parse_ini_file function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

This will convert the input file to an array which can be easily queried.

For example:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file("config.inc.php");
print_r($ini);
```